# Styling highlighted text in incremental search JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First StackOverflow question - woo!

Quick question about styling this piece of Javascript:

```
    //Search
$('#search').keydown(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#search').val() == '') {
            $('#history h4').show();
            $('#history li li').show();
            return;
        }

        $('#history h4').hide();

        var search = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();

        $('#history li li').each(function() {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id').substr(13);
            var item = $.grep(history, function(item) { return item.id == thisId; })[0];
            if (item.message.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1 || item.link.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1)
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 1);
});
});
```

Where do I put the CSS styling in the javascript to highlight the letters in the search results?

```
<font class="highlight"></font>
```

This is similar to searching using Ctrl+F in the browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

JP

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Hi Reinis, Where do I put the styling in the javascript to highlight the letters in the search results with <font class="highlight"></font>?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second `if` statement you could add something like:

```
reg_expression = new RegExp("(" + search + ")","ig");
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(reg_expression, '<span class="highlight">' + "$1" + '</span>'));
```

Note that I´ve used `span` instead of `font` for the `highlight` class.

Also note that I am assuming that your `li li` only contains texts and no html tags because any sequence of characters matching `search` will be replaced by `<span>search</span>` so that could lead to trouble if you have for example links where the `href` value contains your search term.

**By the way,** you need to remove all `span`'s or `fonts`'s before you add the new ones.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thank you very much for your help! The search results do contain html tags - so when I implement it, it returns very messy. Any idea to keep the formatting intact?

Comment: In that case I guess you will have to loop through all elements in `$(this)` and exclude html tags. Something like that...