# How do I trigger ESC button to clear text entered in text box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
   <input type="text" id="search" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I know it is something with

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 27)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare a function which will be called when a key is pressed:

```
function onkeypressed(evt, input) {
    var code = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if (code == 27) {
        input.value = '';
    }
}
```

And the corresponding markup:

```
<input type="text" id="search" size="25" autocomplete="off" 
       onkeydown="onkeypressed(event, this);" />
```

Comment: That works perfect, thank you very much for your help Darin - I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Darin - if you would also help me out with this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615351/styling-highlighted-text-in-incremental-search-js
That would be great!

Comment: Darin: for the keydown event, it's always `keyCode`. All the major browsers have `keyCode` so there's no need to check `charCode`, which is zero or undefined in all current browsers anyway.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) this.value=''" />
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('input[type=text]').each(function (e) {
    $(this).keyup(function (evt) {
        var code = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
        if (code == 27) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" autofocus value="input data" placeholder="ESC button clear" style="padding:5px;">
<p>Hit esc button to see result</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function keyPressed(evt) {
 if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
    //clear your textbox content here...
    document.getElementById("search").value = '';
 }
}
```

Then in your input tag...

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="keyPressed(event)" id="search" ...>
```

Comment: ```onkeypress``` doesn't detect escape, shift, arrow keys etc.  Has to be ```onkeydown``` or ```onkeyup```.